# How to split congruences so moduli are prime powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

If I have the linear congruence x=5 mod 84, is this equal to x=2 mod 3, since 3|84? This seems too easy.

Comment: $x\equiv 5\pmod{84}\implies x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ however $x\equiv 2\pmod{3}\not\Rightarrow x\equiv 5\pmod{84}$

Comment: Of course not, as you can just see with specific numbers; name your favorite number between $10$ and $20$ that's two more than a multiple of 3. Is it 5 more than a multiple of 84?

Comment: The so-called [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), illustrated in [The Mathematical Classic of Sun Tzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Classic_of_Sunzi), says that the residue $\mod 84$ is determined uniquely by the combined residues $\mod 3$, $\mod 4$, and $\mod 7$, i.e. the prime power factors of $84$.

Answer (score 1):

$84 = 3 \times 2^2 \times 7$

By the Chines remainer theorem

$x \equiv 5 \pmod{84} \iff x\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \wedge x\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \wedge x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

---

Doing it the long way...

\begin{align}
   x \equiv 5 \pmod {84}
   &\iff x - 5 = 84n \; \text{for some $n \in \mathbb Z$}\\
   &\iff x - 2 = 84n - 3 \; \text{for some $n \in \mathbb Z$}\\
   &\iff x - 2 = 3(28n - 1) \; \text{for some $n \in \mathbb Z$}\\
   &\implies x \equiv 2 \pmod 3\\
\end{align}